# Submodules of $M/G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm trying to solve this question:

[image]

**ATTEMPT OF SOLUTION**

Let $K$ be a submodule of $M/G$, in particular, $K$ is a subset of $M/G$, then we have $K=m+G$, where $m\in G'', G''$ a subset of M.

We have to prove now that $G''$ is a submodule of M. Since $K$ is a submodule of $M/G$, by submodule criterion, for each $r_1,r_2\in R$ and $m_1,m_2\in G''$, we have $r_1(m_1+G)+r_2(m_2+G)\in K\implies (r_1m_1+r_2m_2)+G\in K\implies r_1m_1+r_2m_2\in G'' \implies K=G''/G$ where $G''$ is a submodule of $M$.

Am I right?

Thanks a lot

**REMARK**

$M$ is a module in a commutative ring $R$ with identity and $G$ is a submodule of $M$

Comment: Context? What is $M$? $G$?

Comment: @BenjaLim yes, sorry

Comment: @BenjaLim is it ok, now?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to write "$K = m + G$ ..." and I don't think that $G''$ is defined very well. I mean, suppose that $K$ is the trivial submodule of $M/G$. Then I could take $G'' = \{0\} \subset M$, and if $G \neq \{0\}$ then this doesn't have the properties that you want. I could take $G''$ to not even be a submodule.

Comment: So it might be better to take $G''$ to be the set of all $m \in M$ such that $m + G$ is an element of $K$. In other words, using the quotient map $\pi\colon M \to M/G$, you would take $G'' = \pi^{-1}(K)$. Make sure that this translation makes sense to you!

Comment: I think this would make your proof that $G''$ is a submodule "go through". But you would still have to prove that $G'' \supset G$, that $K = G''/G$, and that $G''$ is the unique such submodule of $M$.

Comment: @TTS The problem is the book I'm using didn't explain what is a homomorphism yet (I'm using steps in commutative algebra from Sharp)

Comment: @user42912 Ah, well, the first version, then.

Answer (score 3):

Let $K$ be a submodule of $M/G$, by definition any element of $K$ is of the form $m+G$ for some element $m\in M$. Let $G''=\{m\in M: m+G\in K\}$. Let us verify the following facts:

1) **$G''$ is a subgroup of $M$**. Clearly, $0\in G''$, furthermore, if $g,g'\in G''$, then $(g-g')+G=(g+G)-(g'+G)\in K-K=K$.

2) **$G''$ is a submodule of $M$**. Let $g\in G''$ and $r\in R$, then $(rg)+G=r(g+G)\in rK\subseteq K$.

3) **$G\subseteq G''$**. If $g\in G$, then $g+G$ is just the trivial element in the quotient $M/G$ and so it trivially belongs to $K$.

Finally, you have to verify a uniqueness statement, that is, $G''$ is the unique subset of $M$ satisfying 1), 2) and 3) above and such that $G''/G=K$. Suppose that $H$ is another such subset and let us prove that $H\subseteq G''$. Indeed, let $h\in H$, by definition $h+G\in K$ and so $h\in G''$, proving our claim. On the other hand, if $g\in G''$, then $g+G\in K$ and so there exists $h\in H$ such that $g+G=h+G$. In particular, $h-g\in G\subseteq K$, showing that 
$$g=0+g=(h-h)+g=h-(h-g)\in H-G\subseteq H-H=H,$$
which shows that $G''\subseteq H$. Thus, $H=G''$ as desired.